# How to create a progress bar that updates on status change

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting

I'm looking to have a 'Status' column, that a user will change, for example:

- Not started
- Investigating
- Review
- Completed

When the user drops down and selects a status, another column 'Progress' will change.

- When user selects 'Not Started' progress is 0% with a red color
- When user selects 'Investigating' progress is 25% with orange color
- When user selects 'Review' progress is 50% with yellow color
- When user selects 'Completed' progress is 100% with green color

I've seen some guides, but they look to be quite in depth, and they don't seem to cover this exact situation.

Answer (score 3):

You can use SharePoint JSON column formatting for this.

**Example**:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "txtContent": "=if([$Status] == 'Not Started', '0%', if([$Status] == 'Investigating', '25%', if([$Status] == 'Review', '50%', if([$Status] == 'Completed', '100%', ''))))",
      "style": {
        "padding-left": "8px",
        "white-space": "nowrap"
      }
    }
  ],
  "attributes": {
    "role": "progressbar",
    "aria-valuenow": "@currentField",
    "aria-valuemin": "0",
    "aria-valuemax": "1"
  },
  "style": {
    "display": "=if([$Status] == '', 'none', 'block')",
    "padding": "0",
    "color": "=if([$Status] == 'Not Started', 'red', 'black')",
    "background-color": "=if([$Status] == 'Not Started', '#c86c70', if([$Status] == 'Investigating', '#ffa500', if([$Status] == 'Review', '#ffc83d', '#85b44c')))",
    "border-top": "='2px solid' + if([$Status] == 'Not Started', '#a4262c', if([$Status] == 'Investigating', '#8b4000', if([$Status] == 'Review', '#997825', '#498205')))",
    "width": "=if([$Status] == 'Not Started', '0', if([$Status] == 'Investigating', '25%', if([$Status] == 'Review', '50%', if([$Status] == 'Completed', '100%', '0'))))",
    "box-sizing": "border-box"
  }
}
```

**Output**:

[image]

**Documentation**: [SharePoint JSON column formatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting)

**Related JSON sample**: [Multi-Colored Databars](https://github.com/pnp/List-Formatting/tree/master/column-samples/number-data-bar-multi-color)